# Reactiveness in Svelte Input Field Validation

Tags: validation, input, store, svelte

I am using validation against a correct answer while typing in a Svelte input field.
https://svelte.dev/repl/69159ccd80b34d2495bf6642a0f96de9?version=3.44.2

It works perfect, but when changing the correct answer via function to a new value, the reactivity does not apply to the validation store. This is puzzling me because I think according to the documentation it should work and dynamically also update the validation parameters to the new $answer value.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<script>
    import { guessValidator, requiredValidator } from './validators.js'
  import { createFieldValidator } from './validation.js'
    import { writable } from "svelte/store";
    let answer = writable(null);
    let clue = writable(null);
    
    $answer = "Cheese";
    $clue = "I am smelly but tasty"
  
    const [ validity, validate, resetValidation ] = createFieldValidator(guessValidator($answer))

    let guess = null
    
    function nextWord() {
        $answer = "Sun"
        $clue = "I don't shine at night"
        console.log($answer)
        console.log($clue)
    }
    
</script>

<input class="input"
      type="text"
      bind:value={guess}
      placeholder={$clue}
            class:field-danger={!$validity.valid}
            class:field-success={$validity.valid}
      use:validate={guess}
      />
{#if $validity.dirty && !$validity.valid}
<span class="validation-hint">
    {$validity.message} 
</span>
{:else if $validity.valid}
<span class="validation-success">
    Correct!
</span>
{/if}
```

Comment: Without understanding the whole concept I guess line 11 should maybe be reactive `$: [ validity, validate, resetValidation ] = createFieldValidator(guessValidator($answer))` and I wonder if `guess` is reset somewhere and why the values inside `nextWord()` are assigned with parentheses `$answer = ("Sun")`

Comment: Thank you! I removed the brackets - they were wrong - but it doesnt work with the full reactive declaration either. With the $: [ validity, validate, resetValidation ] = createFieldValidator(guessValidator($answer)) the validation isnt working anymore at all for the second word (Sun). With the const declaration the validation still works, but validates against the original answer (cheese), while the clue gets updated correctly in input field placeholder and the value of $answer at this time is correctly updated to 'Sun'. The 'guess' value is ok, since that works.

Comment: The problem is that the new answer value is not validated against dynamically. I also tried let and var instead of const but it doesnt work.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't figure out where exactly the problem in your setup is. I'd probably start from scratch in a new project, adding all logics one after the other and checking reactivity meanwhile and see where it breaks. This is a [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/a1cf8dc218534405a0671788eba7acdf?version=3.44.2) of your (a bit simplified) logic which might maybe be helpful (The variables inside a .svelte component/file don't need to be a store to be reactive)

Comment: Thank you very much, really appreciate this. I will start out with the more simple validation and work from there. ^